# StateProvider angular not working and no error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use angular-ui-route, but, with no errors in console, the stateProvider doesn't work. I am not able to see my homepage  (or any other)..

What am I missing?

my app.js:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'pascalprecht.translate'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$translateProvider', '$interpolateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
   function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $translateProvider, $interpolateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
     $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");

     $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
     $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');

     $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
       prefix: '/static/languages/',
       suffix: '.json'
     })
     .preferredLanguage('pt-br');
     $translateProvider.forceAsyncReload(true);
     $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');
      $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        controller: "HomeCtrl as ctrl",
        templateUrl:"/static/includes/home.html"
      }).state('home.login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl:"/static/includes/login.html"
      });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using ng-view instead of ui-view

Answer (score 0):

Did you Try this

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
```

Instead of

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');
```

Comment: OK, is it the absolute path to your partials ?

/static/includes/login.html

If Not trying using absolute path for instance if your app is in App directory than use 

/App//static/includes/login.html

Also templateUrl is case sensitive. Here in the above code it right but just in case if you have something else in the actual code itself

Comment: I had this exact problem I change version of my angular... the earlier version of angular and ui.router were not compatible with each other.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: :() Man I just saw one feed that guy was using ng-view as well, let me correct him :P

Answer (score 0):

It should be 
`controller: "HomeCtrl"`

instead of

```
controller: "HomeCtrl as ctrl"
```

Controller key would only take the name of the controller.

Comment: I changed it, but nothing happened, it's still not working

Comment: I tried to move my app.js to a folder where I wouldn't need to get my template from the root path, but this doesn't work too, do you have any idea?

Comment: As i didn't have those files, I removed the $locationProvider, $translateProvider and $interpolateProvider from config injection and hence the pascalprecht.translate from the angular.module(). It works pretty well.. So i guess the problem might be with the pascalprecht.translate.. @Gabrielle