# $urlrouteprovider not detecting url for page with jade template rendering

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a url for a download link with a token as follows

```
http://localhost:3000/download/g5ulh69jh8aclhqi
```

In my config.js I have the angular url route provider defined as follows

```
$urlRouteProvider
    .when('/upload/', '/upload')
    .when('/download', '/download')
    .when('/download/', '/download')
    .when('/download/:token', '/download/:token')

    .otherwise(function () {
        var defaultUrl = '/dashboard';
        return defaultUrl;
    });


$stateProvider
    .state('extdownload', {
        url: '/download/',
        abstract: true,
        data: {
            breadcrumbLabel: 'Download url base'
        }
    })
    .state('extdownload.token', {
        url: '/{token:[a-zA-Z0-9]+}',
        templateUrl: '/views/download/download.jade',
        views: {
            '@': {
                controller: 'DownloadController',
                templateUrl: '/views/download/download.jade'
            }
        },
        data: {
            breadcrumbLabel: 'Download page'
        }
    })
```

However whenever I go to the url, the url route provider always defaults to the otherwise clause and goes to the /dashboard url. The url appears as follows

```
http://localhost:3000/download/g5ulh69jh8aclhqi#!/dashboard
```

In my routes.js I render the jade file as follows

```
app.get('/download/:token', can_access.if_not_logged_in(), function(req, res) {
    res.render('download/download', {
        token: req.params.token
    });
});
```

I am stuck as to why it does not properly detect the url in the url provider. Is it because I am rendering a jade file? For other pages, it seems to work just fine

UPDATE 1:

I think this might help but I noticed in the otherwise clause the $location.path() is an empty string. Maybe that is why the url is not matching?

```
{"$$protocol":"http","$$host":"localhost","$$port":3000,"$$path":"","$$search":{},"$$hash":"","$$url":"","$$absUrl":"http://localhost:3000/download/g5ulh69jh8aclhqi","$$replace":false}
```

UPDATE 2:

I added $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); and the URL is now detected. However the stateProvider still does not detect the state. I checked in my downloadController with the $state. It does not get the breadcrumb data in the page.

Another problem is that even with the url being detected correctly I DO NOT see the url displayed below as I am expecting it to

```
http://localhost:3000#!/download/g5ulh69jh8aclhqi
```

Comment: can you see the dashboard content or is it not loading dashboard template as well ?

Comment: It goes to the download page. but the #dashboard is attached to the url instead

Comment: What I meant to say is once the #dashboard is loaded can you see any thing on the screen ? or is it clean ? is it loading the dashboard template ??

Comment: Yeah, I can see the download page clearly. It is rendered correctly as well. There is nothing from the dashboard template.

Update: I added $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); and the URL is now detected. However the stateProvider still does not detect the state. I checked in my downloadController with the $state. It does not get the breadcrumb data in the page

Comment: this is odd, are you using ui.view or ng-view ? It should be ng-view but just for clarification.

Comment: Sorry I mean it should be ui.view NOT ng-view

Comment: I am using ui-view as you can see in the code. Please let me know if it is clear and if it is not I will add it to the main question.
`           // BEGIN PAGE
            // Set margin left in-line so that the page takes full view
            .page-content(style="margin-left:0px;", ng-show="requestCompleted")
                section(ui-view)
`

Comment: So you recommend I change it to section(ui.view)? 
I changed it to ui.view and it did not really make a difference

Comment: are you using ui.router OR $router ? from the code it doesn't look like you are using $router, if you are using ui.router than you need ui-view NOT ng-view, because I've scratch my ass over this problem for a week. and in my case the screen was clean as water nothing was loading althoug url was working fine.

Comment: Also by any chance can you make plunker out of it because looking at code like this and finding a logical error is pretty difficult

Comment: reference to my another post regarding ng-view vs ui.view maybe you find anything which could'nt

http://stackoverflow.com/a/37201067/4578345

Comment: Ill try to make a plunker. Its part of a much larger project for work so Ill try to strip it down as best as I can

Comment: oh and I am using ui.router when creating the overall module. THe below comments have the module and controller

Comment: angular.module('mean.system', ['ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ncy-angular-breadcrumb', 'ui.select2', '

Comment: angular.module('mean.system').controller('DownloadController', [
    '$rootScope',
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    '$modal',
    '$log',
    'API',
    'helperService',

Comment: I don't know, see if you could make plunker you will get more responses as well.